How to delete latest data in Zabbix
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    token = get_zabbix_token()
    failed = False
    
    # Define metric functions to iterate over
    metric_functions = {
        # "ELB": get_elb_metrics,
    }

    for service, metric_function in metric_functions.items():
        try:
            print(f"[INFO] Gathering metrics for {service}")
            for key, name, value, units, namespace in metric_function():
                # Include stage in the metric key and name
                key = f"{STAGE}_{key}"
                name = f"{STAGE} {name}"
                print(f"[DEBUG] Metric: Key={key}, Name={name}, Value={value}, Units={units}, Namespace={namespace}")
                # Check or create Zabbix item
                check_or_create_item(key, name, units, namespace, token)
                # Send metric to Zabbix
                response = send_data_to_zabbix("AWS_metrics", key, value)
                if response["status"] == "failed":
                    print(f"[ERROR] Failed to send metric for {service}: Key={key}, Name={name}")
                    failed = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"[ERROR] Error gathering or sending {service} metrics: {str(e)}")
            failed = True

    # Clear unused metrics
    try:
        clear_unused_metrics(token)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[ERROR] Error clearing unused metrics: {str(e)}")
        failed = True

    # Return response
    return {
        'statusCode': 500 if failed else 200,
        'body': json.dumps("Some metrics failed to send" if failed else "Metrics sent to Zabbix successfully")
    }

def clear_unused_metrics(token):
    items = get_items_to_delete(token)
    item_ids = [item['itemid'] for item in items]
    if item_ids:
        delete_response = delete_items(item_ids, token)
        print(f"Deleted items: {delete_response}")
    else:
        print("No items found to delete.")

def get_items_to_delete(token):
    payload = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.get",
        "params": {
            "output": "extend",
            "hostids": ZABBIX_HOST_ID,
            "search": {
                "key_": "AWS_ApplicationELB"  # Adjust this pattern to match the metrics you want to delete
            }
        },
        "auth": token,
        "id": 2
    }
    response = requests.post(ZABBIX_API_URL, json=payload)
    return response.json().get("result", [])

def delete_items(item_ids, token):
    payload = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "item.delete",
        "params": item_ids,
        "auth": token,
        "id": 3
    }
    response = requests.post(ZABBIX_API_URL, json=payload)
    return response.json()


You have shown us a lot of code, but you haven't explain what specific problem you are experiencing. Please Edit your question and tell us what problem you are having, any errors you are getting and what you'd like it to do. Also, if possibly please only show the code that is relevant to your Question so that we can reproduce your situation. For tips on asking a good question, please see: How do I ask a good question?
